file upload using express JS and react JS
I want to upload a single file from a react frontend to an express server. The file will locally (on frontend) be divided into multiple chunks and then these chunks will be uploaded to the server in parallel (maximum 6 requests at a time), the upload should be resumable, which means if the connection is lost during the upload, then on the next try we don't have to upload the entire file again, it should upload only the remaining parts/chunks.
When all the chunks are received by the server, then they should be joined in the correct order so that we can get the original file back, as it was on the client side before upload. Please let me know how it can be done, I am new to file uploading in a full stack app.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

First you'll need to handle the chunking on the front end


function fileChunker(file, chunkSize = 1024 * 1024) { // default chunk size of 1MB
    let chunks = [];
    let count = Math.ceil(file.size / chunkSize);
    
    for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        let start = i * chunkSize;
        let end = start + chunkSize;
        chunks.push(file.slice(start, end));
    }
    
    return chunks;
}



Then you'll have to deal with the uploading on the front end


async function uploadChunks(chunks, fileId) {
    const uploadChunk = async (chunk, index) => {
        const formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("file", chunk);
        formData.append("index", index);
        formData.append("fileId", fileId);

        return fetch("/upload", { method: "POST", body: formData });
    };

    let promises = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < chunks.length; i++) {
        promises.push(uploadChunk(chunks[i], i));
        if (promises.length === 6 || i === chunks.length - 1) {
            await Promise.all(promises);
            promises = [];
        }
    }
}



Then on the backend, you'll have to handle the save the chunks to disk to merge


const express = require('express');
const multer = require('multer');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();
const upload = multer({ dest: 'uploads/' });

app.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), (req, res) => {
    const { index, fileId } = req.body;
    const filePath = path.join('uploads', `${fileId}-${index}`);

    // Save the chunk to disk with a unique name
    fs.rename(req.file.path, filePath, (err) => {
        if (err) return res.status(500).send('Error saving chunk.');
        res.send('Chunk uploaded successfully.');
    });
});



Then merge


function mergeChunks(fileId, totalChunks) {
    const fileStream = fs.createWriteStream(`uploads/${fileId}`);

    for (let i = 0; i < totalChunks; i++) {
        let chunkPath = path.join('uploads', `${fileId}-${i}`);
        let chunk = fs.readFileSync(chunkPath);
        fileStream.write(chunk);
        fs.unlinkSync(chunkPath); // optionally delete the chunk file after merging
    }

    fileStream.end();
}



